# Memento pattern and violation of encapsulation

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, memento

Across the internet I come across with examples of implementation of **memento** pattern 
which I consider are fully incorrect. 
They can be written in both Java and C#.

Here a several of them

1. [Incorrect implementation of Memento pattern 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/memento_pattern.htm)
2. [Incorrect implementation of Memento pattern 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memento-design-pattern/)
3. [Incorrect implementation of Memento pattern 3](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Memento.aspx)

The code:

```
public class Originator
{
    private string _state; //the private field of originator that shouldn't be exposed!!!!

    public Memento CreateMemento()
    {
        return new Memento(_state);
    }

    public void SetMemento(Memento memento)
    {
        _state = memento.GetState();
    }
}


public class Memento
{
    private string _state;

    public Memento(string state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return _state;  // here caretaker can access to private field of originator!!!
    }
}


public class Caretaker
{
    public Memento Memento { get; set; }
}
```

In code I left comments that should describe situation.

The caretaker class can read private field of originator through memento that violates one of the main principles of memento pattern:

> The object's encapsulation must not be violated.

So the question is am I right?

Comment: I am not a c# specialist, but at least in Java `String`s are immutable, so "exposing" the field should not be a concern?

Comment: @Lino what if it would be for example int type?

Comment: @Lino so are in `c#`

Comment: In java,for example in the first Incorrect implementation of Memento pattern 1

Comment: `int` will be copied at `Memento` constructor, so `Memento._state` and `Originator._state` are 2 different, independent `int`s (same as `string`)

Comment: Yes,technically they are different but anyway we can say for 100% sure that Memento._state ==Originator._state.And so we caretaker can know the value of PRIVATE field of originator

Comment: @vborutenko, no try `object.ReferenceEquals(Memento._state, Originator._state)`. Also, change to `Originator._state` will not change `Memento._state` and vice versa

Comment: Looks like a bit of missundestanding on reference vs. value types

Comment: @vasily.sib but the caretaker class ,in other words, can read the value of private field through momento.It can know the value of the private field.For example the caretakerclass will know that the private field of originator will have for example "someprivatefield" value. Doesn't this violate encapsulation?

Comment: @bradbury9,the missundestanding here that I think that caretaker shouldn't know the value of internal state of originator

Comment: @vborutenko, no, it have no access to `Originator` private field. It stores the **value** (a copy of that `string`/`int`) that was in that field some time ago. So, if `Originator` somehow change his `_state`, `Memento` will never know about this. Same time, if `Momento` somehow change his `_state` (his own copy of that `string`/`int` value) - this will never do anything to `Originator`s `_state`

Comment: OK see the example.Caretaker ask originator to make a new memento.var memento = originator.CreateMemento() . Console.Writeline ( "Hi. I'm caretaker and I know the value of private field '_state' of originator. It equals " + memento.GetState).Doesn't this violate encapsulation?

Comment: @vborutenko, ok, now i see what bothers you. Exposing a **value** (a copy) of a private field is not violates encapsulation. As of your example, there should be _"Hi. I'm caretaker and I know the value of private field '_state' of originator that was equals " + memento.GetState() +  " **some time ago, it may be changed now, IDK**."_

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is am I right?

Yes, you are right: the examples are all incorrect implementations of the Memento design pattern, because the `Memento` class exposes its internal dependency through a public method. As you noted, this allows the `Caretaker` (or any other class) to gain private information about the `Originator`.

Previous answers focus on the state of the internal field and whether the `Memento` state can vary independently of the `Originator`. But encapsulation can be violated in more ways than by exposing state. It can also be violated by exposing dependencies. The public getter method exposes the dependency that `Originator` has on `String`.

I wish I could say that misinformation is unusual regarding design patterns; but you will find inaccurate and misleading articles about design patterns across the Internet, including here on SO and on [Wikipedia](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/1175820397306109952).

I happen to like https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento but it's never a bad idea to crosscheck against the GoF book.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation doesn't mean that you shouldn't be able to access the data at all, you just shouldn't be able to access it directly. You should only be able to access it via public methods :)
This link is probably able to explain it better than i am:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encapsulation-in-java/

So encapsulation is kept in your code example, since the state can only be retrieved via a public get method.

Comment: In originator class we 'hide' the value of the state make it private.We don't want that someone know the value of that field.But in the example we see that caretaker can know this value

Comment: If you dont want to let other classes know about a private property, dont add a public getter that retrieves its value.

Comment: It is implementation of memento pattern from the internet.I provided several links.

Comment: But you made a false assumption because you failed to notice the difference between value and reference types

Comment: No,please see the last comments to the questions

Comment: vborutenko - If you look at the link i referenced. In the very first example of what encapsulation is, they make the private variables accessible via a public get method. You claim the reason why you think the implementations are wrong is because it doesn't adhere to encapsulation, because of the public get method in Memento, but the public get method is a part of encapsulation.Here's another link where this is used, if you are still in doubt : https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

If we add some logic to check how the variables evolve, you will notice how `Originator` and `Memento` are **not** sharing the same data.

```
public class Originator
{
    private string _state = "originator_initial_state";

    public Memento CreateMemento()
    {
        return new Memento(_state);
    }

    public void DoSomeLogic()
    {
        _state = _state + " modified";
    }

    public void SetMemento(Memento memento)
    {
        _state = memento.GetState();
    }
}

public class Memento
{
    private string _state;

    public Memento(string state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return _state;
    }
}
```

Now lets work with them:

```
Originator myOriginator = new Originator();
Memento memento1 = myOriginator.CreateMemento();

myOriginator.DoSomeLogic();

Memento memento2 = myOriginator.CreateMemento();

string memento1_state = memento1.GetState();
string memento2_state = memento2.GetState();

Console.WriteLine(memento1_state);
Console.WriteLine(memento2_state);
```

You will notice that `memento1_state` and `memento2_state` are different, because they do **not** share the same underlying object.

Comment: I understand that they don't share the same object.Please see the last comments to the questions

Comment: If the class provides a getter method, that does not violate encapsulation.